# redirect requests from an application to another

Tags: networking, tcp, server, application-server

Having 2 applications, for commodity let's call it X, Z.

X sends TCP/UDP/HTTP requests to a website/server, then the website/server send back the response to X.

Is it possible to redirect the X requests, to Z instead, and have Z send back the response to X?

I was thinking something like:
X -> proxy/app redirecting everything to Z

Z -> send response back to X

I don't have any access to X source code, so the only possible scenario, I think, is sniffing the packets, and redirect them to Z

Possible?
How?
I accept all ideas and suggestions.

Comment: X is a proxy, itself.

Comment: @RonMaupin No, X is an application that does tasks based on the received response of the server. For example: login verification, start, stop, etc. What I want to do is, that X send the login and any other requests to Z instead.

Comment: Yes, X is the proxy for Z. It is standing in place of Z, between the user and Z. That is a proxy.

Comment: @RonMaupin You didn't get what I mean. X has its own server hosted somewhere, and X communicate to it. Z is an application I will make that will play the role of the server. So, when X for example send a login request to the server with AAA username, even if AAA username doesn't exist in its server, but exist in Z, it will still login in the application. What I want to do is completely cut-off/bypass the X server hosted somewhere, and use my Z instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit X's source code but you can use iptables/netfilter in X's pc, then it can help you.

Comment: Yes, X is an application on my pc, so I can control the network. It's on Windows.
You got any suggestions/idea?

Comment: In Linux you can use iptables / netfilter, in Windows I don't know